# C# HttpWebRequest removing any encoding on an URL

Tags: c#, encoding, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to send percent-encoded ASCII characters using HttpWebRequest, for example https://example.com/%74%65%73%74
Using POSTMAN I'm able to send a request and see in charles that it's still encoded, however, regardless of what I do, any C# library will simplify this to https://example.com/test.
Is there any workaround or async compatible library to work around this?
Thanks in advance

Example Code

```
string newURL = "";
            string path = "test";
            foreach (char character in path)
            {
                string charac = "";
                string finished = "";
                if (character != '-' || character != '/')
                {
                    if (random.Next(1, 10) >= 5)
                    {
                        charac = "%" + Convert.ToInt32(character).ToString("X");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        charac = character.ToString();
                    }
                }
                newURL = newURL + charac;
            }
            string main = "http://www.example.com";
            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(main + "/en/" + newURL);
```

Comment: Please show your c# code.

Comment: It seems to be correct behavior according to this closed [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20126) It depends on what you are trying to achieve but you can try to encode url via `Uri.EscapeUriString`.

Comment: I've tried that however it encodes the % to %25 therefore doesn't work